# Php mysql Get&Post query to excel

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a page that posts to index page like

index.php?coursecode=COURSECODEHERE

My non-variable query works well. Gives me all table as excel file.

I need to use this query with variables.

```
 <?php 
require_once('dbconnect.php');


$setCounter = 0;

$setExcelName = "download_excal_file";

$setSql = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE coursecode POSTED VARIABLE COURSECODE HERE";

$setRec = mysql_query($setSql);

$setCounter = mysql_num_fields($setRec);

for ($i = 0; $i < $setCounter; $i++) {
    $setMainHeader .= mysql_field_name($setRec, $i)."\t";
}

while($rec = mysql_fetch_row($setRec))  {
  $rowLine = '';
  foreach($rec as $value)       {
    if(!isset($value) || $value == "")  {
      $value = "\t";
    }   else  {
//It escape all the special charactor, quotes from the data.
      $value = strip_tags(str_replace('"', '""', $value));
      $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
    }
    $rowLine .= $value;
  }
  $setData .= trim($rowLine)."\n";
}
  $setData = str_replace("\r", "", $setData);

if ($setData == "") {
  $setData = "\n no matching records found\n";
}

$setCounter = mysql_num_fields($setRec);



//This Header is used to make data download instead of display the data
 header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$setExcelName."_Reoprt.xls");

header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

//It will print all the Table row as Excel file row with selected column name as header.
echo ucwords($setMainHeader)."\n".$setData."\n";
?>
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- mysql_ is deprecated, switch to PDO or mysqli ASAP

2.- Always sanitize the input, you never know who may call your link and insert stuff (or delete stuff) from your database.

Said that, you can do something like:

```
$setSql = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE
coursecode LIKE '".sanitizeThisShit($_GET["coursecode"])."'";
```